# Type 3 Slowly Changing Dimension for a Variable Number of Alternate Realities

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap, business-intelligence, multidimensional-array

I'm designing a custom BI application using SSAS with write back operations.  Basically users want to analyze the current state of their sale reps and territories, tweak territory boundaries and assignments in a "what if" scenario, then commit the changes if they like the way that scenario looks.  Each user can have a number of different scenarios to show his/her boss and when a scenario is approved then that becomes the new current state of the sales organization.  I'll be making heavy use of some combination of ROLAP and HOLAP to achieve this.

My boss and I are at odds on how to implement the scenario feature.  He has the executive level summary of how SSAS works and is leveraging his years of experience building database applications while I have been experimenting with SSAS for weeks and read the Kimball bible but I'm still relatively new to multidimensional modeling.  I just need some one who knows what their doing to approve, reject or tweak my idea which is as follows.

I have a number of Type 2 SCD tables that look roughly like this:

```
Create Table SlowlyChangingDimension
(
    SurrogateId Int Identity(1,1) Not Null,
    NaturalId NVarChar(50) Not Null,
    BeginDate DateTime Not Null,
    EndDate DateTime Not Null,
    IsCurrent Bit Not Null,
    IsCommitted Bit Not Null,
    -- Data columns
    Constraint PK_SlowlyChangingDimension Primary Key Clustered (SurrogateId),
    Constraint Ck_SlowlyChangingDimension_DateRange Check (EndDate > BeginDate)
)
```

I maintain historical data through appropriate use of the BeginDate, EndDate and IsCurrent columns.  When new data comes in, I end the current version of the object and create a new current version.

Now to handle scenarios, I want to add a scenario table that I will use to tag specific versions of objects in the SCD.  When a new scenario is created, I will tag the committed versions of each object in the SCD with the scenario.  Since the committed version can exist in multiple scenarios in this way, the M2M link will be facilitated by a bridge table.

Now that the scenario has been created and it's initial state is identical to the committed state, the user can start making changes.  Changes will be stored in the SCD table as additional current rows where IsCommitted = False.  When a change is made, the scenario bridge table will be updated such that it drops the link to the committed version of the object and is now linked to the new alternate version of the object.  When a scenario is committed, the old committed version is ended, the alternate current version is committed and the scenario and all it's links to rows in the SCD table are deleted.

To me, this sounds reasonable.  My boss however, wants to create additional schema elements at runtime when a new scenario is created such that scenario data is stored in separate tables and viewed through a separate cube.  This rubs me the wrong way because I'm pretty sure altering schema at runtime is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Did you ever decide if the answer give below suffices as an accepted answer?  What did you ultimately decide to do, and how did it work out?

Comment: I did not.  We decided not to go with SSAS and the project got canned not too long afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's theoretically possible to programmatically regenerate the schema of an Analysis Services cube at runtime, you still have to wait for processing to occur - which could be very quick for small datasets or very long for lots of data. In practice, however, Analysis Services, is intended to have a relatively static schema. You can handle additional scenarios by adding data and reprocessing the cube - even through incremental updates to make it fast. Budget and forecasting applications typically take this later approach--adding new scenarios through data changes, not schema changes.